# How to compare two images in python

Tags: python, opencv

tried to create OCR program in python,for that i want to compare 2 images (1. extracted character from the image  2. other one images which contain letters).
want to compare these images , if they are same , it should return True otherwise False

Have created function, it returns false even if images are same.

i set both images to 100x100 size

what to do?

```py
found = compimgs("D:/PYTHONS/COUNTOURS/ALPHNOSYMBOLS/SMALL-A.jpg","D:/PYTHONS/COUNTOURS/ALPHNOSYMBOLS/IMROI.jpg")
print(found)

def compimgs(srcimg, dstimg):
im1 = cv2.imread(srcimg,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
im2 = cv2.imread(dstimg,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
#`enter code here`im2 = dstimg
cv2.imshow("EXTRAC-CHAR", im1)
cv2.imshow("MY-CHAR", im2)
diff = cv2.subtract(im1,im2)``
gett = not np.any(diff)
if gett is True:
return True
else:
return False
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. pls tell me , what is SSIM ? I'm a beginner in PYTHON

Comment: It's a technique to determine image differences, here's a good [resource](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/06/19/image-difference-with-opencv-and-python/)